# jQuery moving some text around

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Currently this displays `beds 1, 2, 3, 4` and I need it to display `1, 2, 3, 4 beds` but for the life of me I can't figure out how. Same with baths...it currently displays `baths 2+` and I need it to read `2+ baths`.

jQuery:

```
function bedbathclick() {
  var a = $(this).parents(".bed-bath-pop").prev();
  var finalString;
  var isbaths = false;
  if (a.text().indexOf("beds") > -1) {
    finalString = " beds ";
  } else {
    finalString = " baths ";
    isbaths = true;
  }
  $(".bed-bath-pop").find(".popover-content").find("input:checked").each(function(check) {
    finalString += $(this).val() + (isbaths ? "+" : "") + ",";
  });
  finalString = finalString.indexOf(",") > 0 ? finalString.substr(0, finalString.length - 1) : finalString;
  a.text(finalString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the word (`beds` or `baths`) in another variable for later use (I named it `word`), and concatenate it with your `finalString` at the end.

I would've rearranged the logic so the `beds` or `baths` string is determined at the end, but I saw that you're using an `isbaths` boolean when concatenating the numbered list.

```
function bedbathclick() {
  var a = $(this).parents(".bed-bath-pop").prev();
  var finalString, word;
  var isbaths = false;
  if (a.text().indexOf("beds") > -1) {
    word = " beds";
  } else {
    word = " baths";
    isbaths = true;
  }
  $(".bed-bath-pop").find(".popover-content").find("input:checked").each(function(check) {
    finalString += $(this).val() + (isbaths ? "+" : "") + ",";
  });
  finalString = finalString.indexOf(",") > 0 ? finalString.substr(0, finalString.length - 1) : finalString;
  a.text(finalString + word);
}
```